# Error en unir tablas con limit específico en MySQLi

Tags: php, mysqli

Tengo problemas en unir varias consultas con límites de datos distintos según la materia, teniendo la consulta planteada de la siguiente manera:

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM quiz WHERE materia = 'matematico' LIMIT 40
        UNION
        SELECT * FROM quiz WHERE materia = 'Lenguaje'    LIMIT 30
        UNION
        SELECT * FROM quiz WHERE materia = 'Ciencias'    LIMIT 30
        UNION
        SELECT * FROM quiz WHERE materia = 'Historia'    LIMIT 30
        UNION
        SELECT * FROM quiz WHERE materia = 'Quimica'     LIMIT 30";
```

el problema está en que solo me muestra un solo resultado, cuando en cada materia existen 500 preguntas.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Para poder aplicar `LIMIT` de forma individual a cada consulta, debes envolver cada consulta entre paréntesis,  ejemplo:

```
$sql = "(SELECT * FROM quiz WHERE materia = 'matematico' LIMIT 40)
    UNION
    (SELECT * FROM quiz WHERE materia = 'Lenguaje'    LIMIT 30)
    UNION
    (SELECT * FROM quiz WHERE materia = 'Ciencias'    LIMIT 30)
    UNION
    (SELECT * FROM quiz WHERE materia = 'Historia'    LIMIT 30)
    UNION
    (SELECT * FROM quiz WHERE materia = 'Quimica'     LIMIT 30)";
```

Puedes revisar la documentación aquí: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/union.html